# Melpa package update question

Tags: package-repositories

Last year I created a package for Melpa. I have updated it in my Gitlab repo, but I don't know how to make Melpa aware of that.
Thanks in advance for any tips on that.

Comment: I don't think that should happen. Melpa updates all its packages every few hours. Make sure 1) your package isn't removed from Melpa 2) your git repo is accessible publicly 3) your git repo does contain necessary change to trigger the update, e.g., if you change only the README, the package usually won't update.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I did change my readme, so that must be it.